# The instance of entity type 'Trade' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, blazor

I've been working on this problem for 2 days now, and I can't solve it despite my research.
Let me explain.

In the TradeDetails page, I noticed that only when I use this function set :

```html
    public List<string> ChoosedLabels
    {
        get { return trade.Labels; }
        set
        {

            if (value == null)
            {
                value = new();

            }


            new Task(async () =>
            {

                trade.Labels = value;
                _context.Trades.Attach(trade);
                _context.Entry(trade).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();

     
                await LoadTrade();
            }).Start();

        }
    }
```

On the other page, when I use this portion of code only :

```html
             foreach(var i in trades)
        {
                    if (i.Labels.Contains(labelSupprime.NomLabel))
                    {
                        i.Labels.Remove(labelSupprime.NomLabel);
                    }
                }

                _context.Trades.UpdateRange(trades);
                _context.SaveChanges();
```

This error comes to me:

"The instance of entity type 'Trade' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 62}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."

I know it's due to one of the code snippets I mentioned, but I can't figure out the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first page, change to this code

```
    public List<string> ChoosedLabels
    {
        get { return trade.Labels; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = new();
            }
            new Task(async () =>
            {
                trade = await _context.Trades.FindAsync(trade.Id);
                trade.Labels = value;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                await LoadTrade();
            }).Start();
        }
    }
```

In your second page, try changing the code to be like this

```
        for(int x = 0; x < trades.Count(); x++)
        {
            trades[x] = await _context.Trades.FindAsync(trades[x].Id);

            if (trades[x].Labels.Contains(labelSupprime.NomLabel))
            {
                 trades[x].Labels.Remove(labelSupprime.NomLabel);
            }
        }

        _context.Trades.UpdateRange(trades);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it helps